# Styling the day bar of jQuery UI date-picker calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar, datepicker, themeroller

How to give color background to the day bar of jQuery UI date-picker calendar? with my own custom css? or using the theme roller? has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the table header ui-datepicker looks like:

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Sunday">Su</span></th><th><span title="Monday">Mo</span></th><th><span title="Tuesday">Tu</span></th><th><span title="Wednesday">We</span></th><th><span title="Thursday">Th</span></th><th><span title="Friday">Fr</span></th><th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Saturday">Sa</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a specific class name for the day bar [sun mon tue wed thu fri sat] : is this just a table row?

Comment: There is not a specific class name given with it. It is the first table row in the table head.

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't a class associated with it, you can use the selector `table.ui-datepicker-calendar thead tr:first-child` which should get the job done.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonypawks/2TWKb/) as an example.